# Vbscript Regular expression, find all between 2 known strings

Tags: regex, vbscript

I would like to select all texts between two know strings. Say for example the following text

```
*starthere
*General Settings 
*  some text1
*  some text2
*endhere
```

I would like to select all texts between "*starthere" and "*endhere" using vbscript. so that the final output looks like the following

```
 *General Settings 
    *  some text1
    *  some text2
```

I know this would be simpler using a regex since there are multiple instances of such pattern in the file i read.

I tried something like the following

```
/(.*starthere\s+)(.*)(\s+*endhere.*)/
/(*starthere)(?:[^])*?(*endhere)/
```

But they dont seem to work and it selects even the start and end strings together. Lookforward and backword dont seem to work either and iam not sure if they have support for vbscript.

This is the code I am using:

```
'Create a regular expression object 
Dim objRegExp
Set objRegExp = New RegExp 'Set our pattern
objRegExp.Pattern = "/\*starthere\s+([\s\S]*?)\s+\*endhere\b/" objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
objRegExp.Global = True 
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream 
 strSearchString = objFile.ReadLine
 Dim objMatches
 Set objMatches = objRegExp.Execute(strSearchString)
 If objMatches.Count > 0 Then
  out = out & objMatches(0) &vbCrLf
  WScript.Echo "found"
 End If
Loop
WScript.Echo out
objFile.Close
```

Comment: Look-aheads are supported, but use capturing groups, that is a more efficient way.

Comment: can you provide me an example for that or an ans to this? im fairly new to regex

Comment: anubhava's solution is sufficient. Just use [`Submatches`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y27d2s18(v=vs.84).aspx) collection to retrieve the captured group 1 contents. And to match `*`, escape it as `\*` in the regex pattern.

Comment: @stribizhev yes it seems to find the required data according to [link](http://regexr.com/3bbkn) but when i use it in my vbscript it doesn return any hits.

Comment: this is the code i use `'Create a regular expression object
  
Dim objRegExp

Set objRegExp = New RegExp     
   
'Set our pattern     

objRegExp.Pattern = "/\*starthere\s+([\s\S]*?)\s+\*endhere\b/"    

objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True    

objRegExp.Global = True   
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
strSearchString = objFile.ReadLine
Dim objMatches     
Set objMatches = objRegExp.Execute(strSearchString)
If objMatches.Count > 0 Then 
out = out & objMatches(0) &vbCrLf
WScript.Echo "found"
End If
Loop
WScript.Echo out
objFile.Close `

Comment: The problem is that you have the text split across multiple lines, but you read the file line by line. Check if the line is equal to `*starthere` then build your `out` until the line that equals `*endhere`. No need for RegExp.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
/\bstarthere\s+([\s\S]*?)\s+endhere\b/
```

and grab the captured group #1

`([\s\S]*?)` will match any text between these 2 tags including newlines.

Comment: This works if the string is just "starthere" and "endhere" but im looking for "*starthere" and "*endhere"... Plus i dont want the two tags to show up (*starthere and *endhere) i need only the text in between. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: **i need only the text in between.** That is what you will get in captured group #1 and I mentioned this in answer also.

Comment: Just in case the `*` must be checked for, use `\*starthere\s+([\s\S]*?)\s+\*endhere\b`.